# Webpack loader to get rid of brackets in es6/7

Tags: webpack, coffeescript, babeljs

We've been using CoffeeScript for the last year and really started to like white space instead of curly brackets.

ES6/7 and [babel](https://babeljs.io/) are starting to look really cool and unfortunately CoffeeScript seems to a bit [reluctant/slow in incorporating the new features](https://discuss.bevry.me/t/move-from-coffeescript-to-es6/30). (Probably in part because it's not too easy to do so).

We're thinking about the possibility of creating a webpack loader that would get run as a first step and just look through the js files and based on indentation add curly brackets where it was needed. Like this we could write es6/7 code but not having to write (and read!!) those ugly brackets in the source code :)

Has anybody seem any attempts like this? What consequences would you see in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just gave it a shot. Check out: https://github.com/rstuven/curlyfy-loader

The only big problem I see right now, besides hordes of irritated purists willing to rip my body apart, is there's no IDE support nor syntax highlighting for this.